# mysql-explain: Why will server crash from dependent subquery

Tags: mysql, out-of-memory

On Mysql 5.6, if I run the following query about once per minute:

```
SELECT 
    Count(DISTINCT oxv_oxarticles_de.`oxid`) 
FROM
    oxobject2category 
INNER JOIN 
    oxv_oxarticles_de ON oxobject2category.`oxobjectid` = oxv_oxarticles_de.`oxid` 
                      AND oxv_oxarticles_de.`oxparentid` = '' 
WHERE  
    oxobject2category.`oxcatnid` = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' 
    AND (oxv_oxarticles_de.oxactive = 1 
         AND (oxv_oxarticles_de.oxstockflag != 2 
              OR (oxv_oxarticles_de.oxstock 
                     + oxv_oxarticles_de.oxvarstock) > 0) 
         AND IF(oxv_oxarticles_de.oxvarcount = 0, 1, (SELECT 1 
                                                      FROM 
             oxv_oxarticles_de AS art 
                                                      WHERE 
                 art.oxparentid = oxv_oxarticles_de.oxid 
                 AND ( art.oxactive = 1 ) 
                 AND ( art.oxstockflag != 2 
                        OR art.oxstock > 0 ) 
                                                      LIMIT  1)) )
```

the website will stop responding about every 3 days.

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table             | type   | possible_keys                                   | key       | key_len | ref                                          | rows | Extra                              |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | oxobject2category | ref    | OXMAINIDX,OXOBJECTID                            | OXMAINIDX | 32      | const                                        |   33 | Using where; Using index           |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | oxarticles        | eq_ref | PRIMARY,OXCOUNT,OXSTOCKFLAG,OXACTIVE,parentsort | PRIMARY   | 32      | oxid_erima_prod.oxobject2category.OXOBJECTID |    1 | Using where                        |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | oxarticles        | ref    | OXCOUNT,OXSTOCK,OXSTOCKFLAG,OXACTIVE,parentsort | OXCOUNT   | 32      | func                                         |    5 | Using index condition; Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------+---------+----------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The reported error is

```
mysql error: [5: Out of memory (Needed 1048544 bytes)] in EXECUTE (SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT...
```

This question is not how to "somewhat optimize" the query - although I take those hints with gratitude. I need help to find the smelly part of the query that might simetimes create havoc. Usually (about 99.9%) of the executions take less than 1 ms, with execution being 2 µs.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at how many rows this query examines? I'm pretty sure the query is not what uses all your memory. It's just the first thing that falls on its nose. Look elsewhere.

Comment: @fancyPants: That really makes sense, but in the ~10 cases the site went offline, I always had exactly this query with this in the logs. Since the site does about 30 queries per pageview I assume that's more than a coincidence.

Comment: i find it hard to belief one query would let the system crash.. plus the explain is pretty optimal for this query...you could enable slow_query https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html to slow queries that doesn't use indexes those queries use alot of system resources.. this way you can also see if there are anny badly optimized queries has run just before the crash..

Comment: Thanks, I just enabled the slow query log.

Comment: Check your counts on prepare, execute, close to ensure they are reasonably similar numbers.  Two areas need to be checked.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_stmt_%'  and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com_%_sql'.  Possibility someone forgot to 'close' or 'deallocate' leaving resources that could be free.

Comment: @WilsonHauck: All numbers are 0.

Comment: Good.  This check has eliminated two possible causes of OOM.  If you prepared and executed some routines but did not 'close' or 'deallocate' when done, each one could nibble away RAM availability.  Advanced subject discussed at this link.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%size';
```

You may find one that is 1048544 or some value near that.  Raise that value.

Then ask why you need to count the number of different oxids.

Also, how long does it take for the query to run?  If it is taking more than a minute, then don't run it every minute.  Instead let's work on optimizing it.  For that, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables in question.